# foomatic-configure producing weird perl warnings

Tags: centos, perl, printing, cups

I am using CentOS 6.4 and trying to use the 'foomatic-configure' for print information and am receiving some weird errors:

Perl: v5.10.1

foomatic: foomatic-4.0.4-1.el6_1.1.i686

Command line:

```
foomatic-configure -r -P -q
```

Produces these warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value $manufacturer in string eq at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 354.
Use of uninitialized value $model in string eq at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 355.
Use of uninitialized value in split at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 2147.
Use of uninitialized value $d in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1143.
Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1146.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1146.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1189.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1191.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1193.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1195.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1197.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1199.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Foomatic/DB.pm line 1249.
```

Yukk, what is up with that???

I do receive the perl hash for `$QUEUES[0]` with the correct data, but could do without the error messages....

**UPDATE:**

Looks as though I can suppress these messages using the following:

`foomatic-configure -P -q -r 2>/dev/null`

Shouldn't have to do that though....

Comment: Technically, these are warnings, not errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First two warnings appear in the function `guessmake()` of `Foomatic::DB`. Looking at the code path, `$manufacturer` and `$model` are always undefined, so doing an `eq` comparison does not make sense here, but are harmless here except for the noise. I did not look at the other warnings.

The easist to "fix" this is to remove the `-w` option from `foomatic-configure`'s shebang, so all warnings are disabled. But better to write a bug report to the maintainers.

Comment: I'll file a bug report on this one..Thx!!